# I have a 2009 Yamaha YZF-R6s with a R3 engine is it street legal in Alabama

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

2009 Yamaha yzf-r6s with a r3 engine legal in alabama

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about motor vehicle maintenance and repair.

Comment: Is there come reason why you think it might not be?